# Varchar column from DB transforming to hex when it goes to EXCEL

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel

I'm querying some values from my SQL Server database and one of these values is defined like this:

```
varchar(30)
```

And when i add it to my excel, i do it like this:

```
xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 2] = Convert.ToString(item[1]);
```

But here's what's happening:

A value like '09531576000230' is converted to '9,53158E+12'. What am i missing here?

Comment: The cell/column format is set to "General" which automatically presents the scientific notation. Set it to Number and it should be fixed.

Comment: Last I checked, neither `,` nor `+` were *generally* considered to be "hex".

Answer (score 1):

Try creating an Excel workbook and formatting all of the cells as text, and then pasting in the data.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to I. Zain and Jacob H i solved my problem like this:

```
Range r = xlWorkSheet.Cells;
 r.NumberFormat = "@";
```